# Maven install of nd4j fails with incorrect path to pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Following the installation instructions from [here](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j):

I try:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j.git
```

then:

```
$ cd nd4j
$ mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -e
```

This fails with the exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \desktop-g6h5sva\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\nd4j\desktop-g6h5sva\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\nd4j\pom.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

The path to my working directory is repeated twice in this case and so maven can't find the file. Any idea what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: try cd \\desktop-g6h5sva\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\nd4j\desktop-g6h5sva\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\nd4j\         you will know whether this path is correct or not

Comment: the specified directory does not exist.  pwd gives:  \\desktop-g6h5sva\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\nd4j